# ¿ Como puedo cambiar el color de una celda al pulsar en ella y guardar ese valor?

Tags: php

Quiero hacer una tabla para disponibilidad horaria semanal, y quiero que el usuario de mi web pueda marcar en esa tabla las horas que tiene libres, y deseo hacer eso dejando que el usuario pueda marcarlas, y se guarden esos valores en una base de datos, he visto algo asi

```
function mark_complete(i){
         if(confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed with this action?')){
            $('tr').click(function () {
                if(this.style.background == "" || this.style.background =="white") {
                    $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
                    $.ajax({     
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'addColor.php',
                        data: {color:'yellow'},
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);   
                        },
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css('background', 'white');
                    $.ajax({     
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'addColor.php',
                        data: {color:'white'},
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);   
                        },
                    });
                }
            });
         }
}
```

pero no se como utilizar este código ni donde ponerlo ni como asignar eso a mi tabla
y para que lo guarde en la base de datos he visto estes archivo llamado addcolor.php que tampoco se donde ponerlo :

```
    $color = $_POST['color'];
    $con = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_databasename);
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE `color_tbl` SET `color` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $color);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

agradeceria si alguien puede ayudarme